# How to route from one application to another application in angular 2+

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have two different application in angular 7 and I want to navigate between them. How do I achieve it by using angular routing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, you cannot. Angular Routing works within an Angular application, so both applications will have their own Angular router and router configuration.

The only way you can "route" to another application would be to use `window.location.href`.

It is worth noting that in doing this you will be unloading the existing Angular application and loading in the new Angular application (in other words all the state, assets and files of the current application will be unloaded from the browser), navigating backward and forwards between these two apps could get expensive as each app will be loaded and started everytime you navigate to the app.

It may be worth considering having the two "apps" inside a single Angular app as modules or [sub-applications](https://medium.com/disney-streaming/combining-multiple-angular-applications-into-a-single-one-e87d530d6527) where you would then be able to route to them using lazy loading.

For example, your router configuration would look something like this

```
[
  { path: 'app1', loadChildren: 'path/to/module/for/app1#ModuleName' },
  { path: 'app2', loadChildren: 'path/to/module/for/app2#ModuleName' }
]
```

Then in your application, you can use `this.router.navigate(['/app1'])`

I hope that helps.

Comment: the problem that i am facing with href is... i have my main app in mydomain.com root, and i have my second app in mydomain.com/shop... well if you load first the main app, once the main app loads, it cant navigate to mydomain.com/shop because it 
 doesnt recongnize de route... even if a move to a component that has an window.location.href... it enters in a loop...

Answer (score 4):

use `window.location.href='externalurl'`