# How to navigate from one app to another app in Angular Nx?

Tags: angular, nrwl-nx, nrwl

I have multiple angular applications in root folder with libs. I need to navigate from one app to another. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/UokZL.png)

How should be routing for this case?

Comment: Check this out :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/55869698/15406039


https://medium.com/disney-streaming/combining-multiple-angular-applications-into-a-single-one-e87d530d6527

Comment: @sfelli, Thanks!  I have already checked that, It says to create module instead of application and lazy load it. But here is the different case. I need to navigate from one app to another app (without creating module).

Comment: Wlc, try to use window.location.href='externalurl'